# Joomla 3 Content Restriction

Tags: joomla

I have a single article and I want to display a portion of the content to the Registered user group only and the other portion to a Custom user group only.

I'm sure I read an article sometimes int he past year about doing this without a plugin (Though I may be mis-remembering the article)

Is this possible without an extension using something along these lines?

{content group=registered}

Comment: As far as I know, this feature doesn't come by default with Joomla, and therefore you will have to use a 3rd party plugin. I would usually recommend a few examples of good extensions to use, based on previous experience, however I have never needed to do this.

Comment: This is a cheating hack but if it is just just one article you could make two custom HTML modules with different access levels matching your two groups and use loadposition to show them (except that the ones the users don't have access to won't show).

Comment: Thanks Elin, But my issue is hiding it once the user is Registered. I manually approve accounts, but once I change them to a higher level, the module for Registered still shows. There is no ACL for 'viewing'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using the jContentHider plugin. While I still had do some work arounds, I got it working the way I want to.

For others interested:

[jContentHider on GitHub](https://github.com/jitendra-khatri/jcontenthider)

Comment: Just an update that this solution has been working well for me.

Comment: You can try this as well http://joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/membership-pro-joomla-membership-subscription.html

Comment: @Apurv that link is a 404

Comment: Surprising, I can open the link. Its 'Membership Pro' component from joomdonation.com

Comment: Very weird... yesterday I got the Joomla 404 page, today it works. Clicked the same link! YAY Technology!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a category (with limited access) say `Registered`. Create another category with restricted access say `Paid_Access`.

Now for every article create two articles - one in `Registered` category containing only Intro text and another full article in `Paid_Access` category.

Create Access Group and Access levels with same name

The hierarchy of the access levels will be as follows:

- Public

  - Registered

    - Paid_Access

Set the `Registered` category to access level `Registered`. Set the `Paid_Access` category to access level `Paid_Access`

By default, on Joomla registration every user will be in `Registered` access level and will be able to only view article intro.

When user make some payment, move the user to `Paid_Access` access level. Users in this level can view the complete article.

Creating two articles for every new article may be cumbersome, to reduce this pain, you can create a custom form using [ChronoForms](http://www.chronoengine.com/). This form should have two text areas for the article - one would be for Intro text and another full article (without Intro text). The form while saving, will itself create two articles - one in `Registered` and another in `Paid_Access`. Thus your pain of creating two articles will be gone!

Comment: Thanks Apruv, but my issue doesn't lie in hiding and showing the content.

It's that I can't hide something set to display to Registered group from higher groups. Hiding from public is easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without a plugin.

**Reason :** When Joomla is preparing content then there must be a function(code snipet) that detects the Text enclosed in {content} tags and decide what to do with this text and accordingly edits the content.

I have developed a Content Plugin, This will helps you https://github.com/jitendra-khatri/jcontenthider to setup your scenario.

Answer (score -2):

You could do this with CSS if your template adds the access level as a class on the body or html (mine do). Though anyone with firebug or a code inspector could unhide content if they thought to look at the source.

```
<body class="registered">
 // other code up to article content
 <div id="articleContent">
  // this is now in your article
  <div class="hidefrompaid">
    // content for registered users
  </div>
  <div class="hidefromregistered">
   // content for paid users
  </div>
 </div>
...
```

Then your css would be:

```
body.registered .hidefromregistered {
display:none;
}

body.paid .hidefrompaid {
display:none;
}
```

Or if you really want to not show it you could use jQuery to delete the text the user should not see using those same css classed wrappers around the text.

```
jQuery('body.registered').find('.hidefromregistered').remove();

jQuery('body.paid').find('.hidefrompaid').remove();
```

Comment: This would be very kiddish to do, as there is money involved.

Comment: I was only using paid as an example, he just said custom, we don't know if it is paid. This is a quick and dirty way to get it done. And besides capitalism kills. What is kiddish is comments like this on SO.